# Determining the data type of CSV columns

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I have a plain text dataset, csv separated by commas and I would like to implement a script that allows me to determine the type of data that each attribute is. That is to say, to tell me if it is integer, string, date...

Here's a sample of the dataset

```
"date","name","age","ID"
05/08/12,John Smith,19,ES1836549
```

I think the only thing that could help me is to implement regular expressions to check it. Any idea?

Comment: You can never 'detect' a data type correctly in all instances. For example - if you meet the value '2020' is it a string, a number or a year? Or 2020.01.01? Could be a date or a version string? You would need to look at all values in a column and look for patterns, but even then it's unlikely to be foolproof. In your specific example ... you have a column title and that might be your best bet to detemine a datatype. For example, anything called 'date' would expect to be of some date format, 'age' would likely be an integer, 'name' always a string, etc.

Comment: I think you're approaching this question backwards: you should know what datatype the columns _should be_, and you want to validate that the actual contents match the datatype. The validation could be "the date column should match one of these valid date formats", "the age column must not contain non-digits", "the ID column should match this regular expression", etc

Comment: Hi @glennjackman yes something like that! Looking at the dataset I already know what type of data I have, however I need to generate an output similar to "column 3 is type integer".

Comment: Then I'd agree that using regular expressions is the right way to go. You'll need to use bash arrays, and you'll have nested for loops, and a cascading if statement. A warning: free-form date parsing is quite difficult to get right: `99/99/99` might pass a simplistic date validation regex but is clearly not a date.

Comment: @glennjackman Could you provide some basic example code to guide me? I would appreciate it very much

Comment: No, you make an effort first, add some code to your question, and then we can help you from there. That's how this works.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1):

Starting from:

```
seq,name/first,age,dollar,date
1,Samuel,18,2016.35,06/26/1918
2,Jerome,18,6022.22,01/25/1959
3,Jeremiah,31,4842.38,08/17/2065
4,Mitchell,52,5579.49,01/20/1919
5,Philip,48,8708.53,09/27/2043
6,Mayme,63,3381.63,04/02/1968
7,Theresa,45,3427.57,03/29/1954
8,Dorothy,51,662.90,07/08/2070
9,Olga,45,4456.29,02/16/2051
10,Lee,65,884.33,05/09/1913
```

Two tools:

- [frictionless](https://github.com/frictionlessdata/frictionless-py)

```
frictionless validate input.csv --json
```

gives you

```json
        "schema": {
          "fields": [
            {
              "type": "integer",
              "name": "seq"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "name": "name/first"
            },
            {
              "type": "integer",
              "name": "age"
            },
            {
              "type": "number",
              "name": "dollar"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "name": "date"
            }
          ]
        }
```

- [xsv](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv)

```
xsv stats  --everything input.csv
```

gives you

```
+------------+---------+-------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------+-------------+
| field      | type    | sum               | min        | max        | min_length | max_length | mean               | stddev             | median             | mode | cardinality |
+------------+---------+-------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------+-------------+
| seq        | Integer | 55                | 1          | 10         | 1          | 2          | 5.5                | 2.8722813232690143 | 5.5                | N/A  | 10          |
| name/first | Unicode |                   | Dorothy    | Theresa    | 3          | 8          |                    |                    |                    | N/A  | 10          |
| age        | Integer | 436               | 18         | 65         | 2          | 2          | 43.6               | 15.660140484682762 | 46.5               | N/A  | 8           |
| dollar     | Float   | 39981.69000000001 | 662.9      | 8708.53    | 6          | 7          | 3998.1690000000003 | 2348.632561630065  | 3941.9300000000003 | N/A  | 10          |
| date       | Unicode |                   | 01/20/1919 | 09/27/2043 | 10         | 10         |                    |                    |                    | N/A  | 10          |
+------------+---------+-------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------+-------------+
```